# XPath for child element relative to parent element

Tags: xml, xpath

I have

```
<A>
  <B>...</B>
  <C>...</C>
  <D>...</D>
</A>
```

I have `A` element currently and from there I want to get element `C`.
I tried doing `"child::[local-name()='C']"`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Also, is there a good XPath resource other than W3school?  W3school didn't have much explanation for `local-name()`.

Comment: use : /A/C. or / child::A/child::C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have A element currently and from there I want to get element C.

Given that you've shown `C` to be a child of `A`, the relative XPath from `A` to `C` is `"child::C"` in unabbreviated syntax or simply `"C"` in abbreviated syntax.

> Also, is there a good XPath resource other than w3school?

Consider instead going to the authoritative source, [W3C XML Path Language (XPath)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), which is actually very readable.  Don't miss the examples in the [Location Paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths) and [Abbreviated Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) sections.

Answer (score 0):

In the given xml you can use the xpath "/A/C" the get the element  it refers from the root node.

If you want to get it from the actual node you can use "./C".

Remember that XPath is case sensitive.